# how to add specific row and columns from pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data set like below but when i tried to sum column it will sum from the year. what i want is sum from Jan to Dec.

the code which i tried is`data.sum(axis=0)`

```
Out[64]: 
    year  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
0   1981   32   26   62   22   23   98   80  163   13  122  144  109
1   1982   42   30   54   50  192   37   52   77   48   46   74   52
2   1983   78   10  107   46   36  105   80   25  188   58   36   78
3   1984   72   29   34   11   29   97   67   51  145  114   51   51
4   1985   83   37   42   69   23   25  104   50   76   53   74   63
5   1986   50   12   69   51   77   39  121  234   56   45   54   89
6   1987   23   28   22    4   55   77   92  122   65   34   54   24
7   1988   72   64   40   37   41   51  106  173   36   69   38   66
8   1989    9   28   51   55   38   42   11   68   23   74   55   59
9   1990   74   79   56   46   30   25  128   42  153   79   60   42
10  1991   59   29   41   24   78  142   54  124   71   27   47   37
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the columns first and then `sum`:

```
In [274]:
df[df.columns[1:]].sum(axis=0)

Out[274]:
Jan     594
Feb     372
Mar     578
Apr     415
May     622
Jun     738
Jul     895
Aug    1129
Sep     874
Oct     721
Nov     687
Dec     670
dtype: int64
```

If you want to sum row-wise pass `axis=1`:

```
In [291]:
df['total'] = df[df.columns[1:]].sum(axis=1)
df

Out[291]:
    year  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec  total
0   1981   32   26   62   22   23   98   80  163   13  122  144  109    894
1   1982   42   30   54   50  192   37   52   77   48   46   74   52    754
2   1983   78   10  107   46   36  105   80   25  188   58   36   78    847
3   1984   72   29   34   11   29   97   67   51  145  114   51   51    751
4   1985   83   37   42   69   23   25  104   50   76   53   74   63    699
5   1986   50   12   69   51   77   39  121  234   56   45   54   89    897
6   1987   23   28   22    4   55   77   92  122   65   34   54   24    600
7   1988   72   64   40   37   41   51  106  173   36   69   38   66    793
8   1989    9   28   51   55   38   42   11   68   23   74   55   59    513
9   1990   74   79   56   46   30   25  128   42  153   79   60   42    814
10  1991   59   29   41   24   78  142   54  124   71   27   47   37    733
```

Comment: I don't understand you're saying `data[data.columns[1:]].sum(axis=1)` doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry but I don't see that as my code works fine for me

Comment: pass `axis=1` to sum row-wise

Comment: Sorry I can,t do that because my score is less then 15..it says that for vote we should have at least 15 score. and aslo could you please tell me how to calculate coefficient of variation for each month, I have tried  import                  scipy.stats as ss and then 

ss.variation(df) but I the values are not in order

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the year column and sum the month columns:

```
data.drop('year', axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

But I guess you would want keep the year info for each sum. A better way would be set the year column as an index and sum:

```
data.set_index('year').sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: could you please help me to calculate coefficient of variation from above data sets?